# how to add id and name scope with access token and insert into database using graph api

Tags: php, mysql, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I have this code on my script, and I want to scope id and name of the user with the access token and insert it on my database;

```
    public static function me($data){
    if(User::authenticated()){
        $fb['me'] = @file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={$_SESSION['TOKEN']}");
        $fb['me'] = json_decode($fb['me']);
        return $fb['me']->$data;
    } else {
        return "ERROR: Not logged in";
    }
}
```

}

It's using facebook's graph api. And also i'd like to scope the facebook user id and name not only the access token. It will be inserted in my database with this query;

```
if(isset($_POST['act'])){
switch($_POST['act']){
    case "login":
    if(Token::check(Token::extract($_POST['token']))){
        $_SESSION['TOKEN'] = (Token::extract($_POST['token']));
        $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO {$pref}topkek VALUES('', :token)");
        $insert->execute(
            array(
                "token" => $_SESSION['TOKEN']
            )
        );

        if($insert){
            $r = array("status" => "true", "message" => "Token validated. Redirecting...");
        } else {
            $r = array("status" => "false", "message" => "Query failed.");
        }
    } else {
        $r = array("status" => "false", "message" => "Invalid or Expired Token.");
    }
    break;
```

What I want to know is how will it scope the facebook user's id and name when getting the token and to be inserted in the database with the code provided below. And also if the token matches or the user's id matches with a record in database, it will just replace the token with the id that matched.

Comment: What is the reason you are not using Facebook SDK for PHP?

Comment: @awons my old friend coded this, but i cant contact him anymore. Thats why im the one modifying it right now. And i dont know much with fb graph api.

Comment: I would really consider switching to SDK. And play with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/.

Comment: @awons i'd like too but i'm not that experienced with both. it's like i just modify the code every now and then but i don't have vast knowledge with it. that's why i was asking some people because i can't reach my old friend anymore for help. if anyone could help me, i'd gladly give them a linux vps with root access.